# Get a Copy of MQ Message without impacting current producer and consumer

Tags: ibm-mq

Is there a way to read the MQ message without impacting the current producer and consumer?

We have a consumer already to read from a MQ, but we want to feed the same messages in the MQ to some other places. Is there way to do that without touching the MQ producer nor the existing consumer?

I searched around and found there's something called queue browse. Can I set up another consumer for this MQ and only do browsing? Will both the old and new consumer be able to get all messages?

The producer is not owned by us, so can't change the configuration of it.

So the best option is to not touch producer + consumer; But if no other choice, we can try modify a bit of the existing consumer.

Are there any ways? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are at MQ 9.3 you can configure a steam queue which will get a copy of each message that is put to the existing queue.  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=scenarios-streaming-queues

Comment: If you are not at 9.3 you can configure the producer to PUT to an ALIAS queue that points to a TOPIC and then subscribe the original queue and a second queue to the topic string of that TOPIC.

Comment: Capitalware has MQ Message Replication that will do this on any version of MQ: https://capitalware.com/mqmr_overview.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoshMc! Those are great ways. But given the producer is not owned by us, is there a way to avoid touching the producer too? (I updated my question a little bit too)

Comment: At some point the message created by the producer must land on a queue on your queue manager - can't you use streaming (or put to alias or message replication) at that point?

Comment: Do you own the queue manager the consumer is connected to for reading the queue?

Comment: @JoshMc, unfortunately, I do not own the queue manager

Comment: In that case there's isn't any MQ magic you can do on the client side that will help you.   A single app would need to read the messages and then process the message and hand it of in some way to some other places.

Comment: If you had a queue manager and then messages were sent from the existing queue manger to your queue manger then you would have the options discussed earlier available.   If the owner of the queue manger is willing to do those changes then they may still be an option for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoshMc, your response is really helpful! I will check with the owner of the queue manager to see if they can help on this. Appreciate it so much!